# Nginx trailing slash in proxy pass url

Tags: nginx, proxy, proxypass

I am using nginx to proxy pass to a NodeJS application. I'm trying to make the URL `https://example.com` proxy pass the request to `http://example.com:8080/?`

Requests (from a mobile app) are requesting `https://example.com//` which nginx is making `http://example.com:8080//?` which is not working.

Things I have tried which haven't worked:

- `merge_slashes on;` (which is on by default)
- `rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;`
- `port_in_redirect off;`

My nginx config:

```
location = /a {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
}

location ^~ /a/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
}
```

Comment: - see > To slash or not to slash \ https://dev.to/danielkun/nginx-everything-about-proxypass-2ona \
- it seems that: nginx takes in the `url path (including the first slash)` & trims out the front part you specify in `location` & just append the rest to the `proxy_pass` \
- the rules for cases of root path `/` or `if proxy_pass used without URI (see another answer post)` seems different though \
- you may test using https://nginx-playground.wizardzines.com (though, not sure what is configured behind (correct or not) & limited though)

Answer (score 75):

I guess you use proxy_pass without URI. In that case nginx pass original URI as it was, not normalized one. So you should use `proxy_pass http://backend/;`

**UPDATE**

So I was right. Just add URI part to proxy_pass like this:

```
location = /a {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/a;
    ...
}

location ^~ /a/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/a/;
    ...
}
```

As stated in [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass) if `proxy_pass` used without URI (i.e. without path after server:port) nginx will put URI from original request exactly as it was with all double slashes, `../` and so on.

On the other side, URI in `proxy_pass` acts like [`alias`](http://nginx.org/r/alias) directive, means nginx will replace part that matches location prefix (in our case it's `/a` in first location and `/a/` is second) with URI in `proxy_pass` directive (which I intentionally made the same as location prefix) so URI will be the same as requested but normalized (without double slashes and all that staff). **Be careful** with trailing slashes. Nginx replaces part literally and you could end up with some strange url.

Here is an example with trailing slash in `location`, but no trailing slash in `proxy_pass`.

```
location /one/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/two;
    ...
}
```

If you go to address `http://yourserver.com/one/path/here?param=1` nginx will proxy request to `http://127.0.0.1/twopath/here?param=1`. See how `two` and `path` concatenates.

Comment: Apologies for less information but my proxy pass settings are as follows::  location = /a {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_read_timeout 300;
        }

        location ^~ /i/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001/;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_read_timeout 300;

Comment: @PratyayModi put it in question. It's hard to read it in comment

Comment: I had added the / after 8080 but not the complete path, let me try this does look promising...

Comment: Thanks man, It works.. would you please explain why putting the redirect line did not work and this works after putting an extra /. iF I understand correctly. we just told nginx exactly where to go so it eliminated the extra / on its own.

Comment: Updated answer. Almost all nginx directives work with normalized URI, so your `rewrite` directive just didn't match.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyTen, this was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You might add these lines:

```
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Example, I proxy public port 80 to local port 880

```
location / {
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_connect_timeout 90;
            proxy_send_timeout 90;
            proxy_read_timeout 90;
            proxy_buffer_size 16k;
            proxy_buffers 32 8k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;

            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:880/;
    }
```

**Note: Make sure to restart nginx. You might need to use another browser to test the new configuration (avoid cache)**